# Updating Android APK in different language?

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I have an Android app on the Play Store, built in Xamarin. I'm going to rewrite using Java and Android Studio - is there anything stopping me from updating/switching language on my already-published app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure to use:

- the same **`Package Name`**
- the same **`signature`** you signed the old one with
- a bigger **`Version Code`** than the previous one.